# emberjs nested dynamic route segment returning null and unable to update child record

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

I am trying to implement a **comment-feature**, to display a list of comments that belongs to a single post. Then click edit and edit any of the selected comments from from all the comments that belong to a single post.

**Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VrR2T/1/)**.

I am able to create a comment that belongs to the selected post as seen in the fiddle above. **However I am unable to updating an existing comment and the comment edit form won't even display any comment. It is always blank and doesn't bind to any existing comment.

Clicking on editcomment the url is **posts/2/comments/undefined/edit**. This is because EmBlog.PostCommentRoute & PostEditCommentRoute are still returning null.

All the commented out code are the different attempts at getting it to work that has failed. I left them here, so anyone looking at the question will know what I have tried so far.

**The two routes that always return null and most likely causing the problem**

```
 EmBlog.PostEditCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
   var commentEdit = this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
   return commentEdit.get(params.comment_id);

   //return EmBlog.Comment.find({post: post.get('id'), id: params.comment_id});

   //var comment = this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
   //return comment.filterProperty('id', params.comment_id);  
  },

  setupcontroller: function( controller, model) {
  controller.set('content', model);
  }
});
```

The Comment route to display single post

```
EmBlog.PostCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params){  
     comment = this.modelFor('post').get('comments');
    // comment = EmBlog.Comment.find(params.comment_id);

    return comment.get(params.comment_id);
    // return comment.filterProperty('body', params.comment_id);
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    //var comment = this.controllerFor('postComments').get('body');
    //controller.set('content', comment.filterProperty('body', model));

    controller.set('content', model);
  },

});
```

This is the router. I have tried other combinations of nesting but settled on this one because it was the only version that allowed adding a comment to work, which is why this question is focused on updating a nested dynamic segment only otherwise I would been asking about both:

```
 EmBlog.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("posts", {path: '/posts'}, function(){
      this.route('new');

      this.resource('post', {path: '/:post_id/'}, function(){
        this.route('edit', {path: '/edit'});
        this.route('comments', {path:  '/comments'});
        this.route('newComment');
        this.route('comment', {path: '/comments/:comment_id'});    
        this.route('editComment', {path: '/comments/:comment_id/edit'});       
     }); 
   });
});
```

Comment: here this one moves you a little bit further.  I get the correct path for the comment edit, and the content shows up in the text area for the comment. http://jsfiddle.net/VrR2T/4/  The main issue was your context where all messed up.  I assume that you wanted to loop over all the comments, display them with edit link, then have a link  to add a new one.

Comment: Many thanks Fred. Yes your assumptions are right, and everything now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified the loop.  Before you were not passing a context hence you were getting undefined in the path.  Now you are passing each comment to linkTo so it can generate the proper route.  Here is a link the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VrR2T/4/

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/comments">
  <h1> Yes Comments template</h1>

    <p> {{#linkTo "post.newComment"}} Add comment{{/linkTo}}</p>
    <br/>
    {{#each comment in content}}
        <br/>
          {{comment.body}} <br/> 
     <p>{{#linkTo "post.editComment" comment}} Edit Comment {{/linkTo}}</p>

    {{/each}}
  {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Here is the updated form.  need to bind to content.body

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post/_commentForm">
   <form {{action save on='submit'}}>
{{view Ember.TextArea valueBinding="content.body" placeholder="body"}}
<button type="submit"> save comment </button> 
 <button {{action 'cancel' content}}> Cancel</button>
</form>
</script>
```

Comment: I tried awarding you the bounty and it flashed a message in red  that I may award it in 17 hours. So I will award it immediately stackoverflow allows me too. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded your code from the fiddle and found a few problems.

**First**

You accidentally used `Ember.Router` instead of `Ember.Route` below.

```js
EmBlog.PostCommentsRoute = Ember.Router.extend({
// ...
EmBlog.PostCommentRoute = Ember.Router.extend({
```

Should be

```js
EmBlog.PostCommentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
// ...
EmBlog.PostCommentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
```

**Second**

You didn't need to override `model` in this route, the default Ember behavior is fine. You're also referencing `params_id` when that variable has not been declared.

```js
EmBlog.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
     post = this.modelFor('posts');
     return post.get(params_id);
    //return EmBlog.Post.find(params.post_id);
    //return this.modelFor('post').filterProperty('id', params.post_id);
  },
```

**Third**

*in response to your comment below*

The problem is that you're linking to editComment from within the context of the post, not the comment itself. Once that was fixed, I also changed the TextArea to be `model.body` instead of `body`.

The changes are itemized [in this Gist](https://gist.github.com/mutewinter/5375921). Now the editing needs to be implemented.

Comment: Thanks @mutewinter. I have updated the **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RFLbV/15/)** with the corrections. I have 1 problem, EmBlog.PostCommentRoute & PostEditCommentRoute are still returning null. Clicking editcomment the url is **posts/2/comments/undefined/edit**. In the jsfidde, you will see that I have tried the various methods I know, using various permutations to see it works and then i commented out each one that didn't work but left them in the code just to know what i have tried. This also means while the form to edit a comment displays, it doesn't bind to any existing comment. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

problem 1: i think it would help if you didn't change the path and kept it as '/:post_id'

problem 2: sorry, i don't think i can help here.

Comment: Thanks @finn. I will change the path back to '/:post_id' and try it out from there. Thanks for your time.

Comment: np. also, since you're working on a blog as well, maybe you can use some of the code [here](https://github.com/FinnMacCool/ember-rails-blog).

Comment: ok thanks, I will look through the source code in that repo. many thanks.

Comment: why not? i think the path may very well be the reason his code doesn't work. i might be wrong, but it's an answer nonetheless.

Comment: @finn, in the updated fiddle, I have kept at the path '/:post_id" and generally used the structure you suggested in the other question.  but the comments template is still not being rendered and all the templates nested under it. I have reworded my question and remove all references to rails, since the problem is actually emberjs.

Comment: I just manged to get the main comments template to display using the render helper but not the #linkTo helper. **But the templates nested under the comments.hbs are still not displaying.** I have updated the jsfiddle again.

Comment: Great the templates nested in comments.hbs are now displaying but the #linkTo not working. jsfiddle update again.

Comment: hmm, you're linking to 'comments.index', but i can't seem to find any 'comments/index' template or a corresponding view that uses another template (or a corresponding route or controller, for that matter). also, i still think the comment routes should be reordered, but that's maybe just my taste.

Comment: p.s.: i don't know if it works or not, but i wouldn't put a button inside a link like you do in the 'comments/comment' template. i'd either use a link and call the action in the corresponding route's setupController hook or use a button and call `transitionToRoute` somewhere in the action.

Comment: Ok I will try and take the button out and not enclose it in a link. cheers