# EMBER URL contains undefine while transitionToRoute

Tags: ember.js

When I was trying to  transition to another route ,I got `#/projects/undefined` rather than what I expected :`#/projects/1`

Here is part of my code. I put the source code at jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kago/ctXqn/

```
App.ProjectsRoute=Em.Route.extend({
    model:function(){
        return this.get('store').find('project');
    },

    actions:{
        filterBoardByPid:function(id){
        var m = this.get('store').find('board',{pid:id});
        this.get('controller').transitionToRoute('boards',m);
        }
    }
});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('projects',function(){
        this.resource('boards',{ path: "/:project_id"});
    });
});
```

My Ember version is:

> ember.js (Version: v1.0.0-77 2013-09-09)`and`ember-data.js(Version: v1.0.0-beta.1 2013-09-09)

Questions

1. How can I get the right URL?
2. Am I on the right way to achieve this?

---

UPDATE: 2013-9-25

My Data Structure:

I have several `projects`, in each `project` I have several `boards`,In the future I am going to put several `comps` in each `board`.

My UI intension

' / '----------> a link， show the projects list

' /projects '---------->projects list,each link to the sub-route。eg:"projects/1"

' /projects/1 '---------->boards list ,which belong to `proj1`

> For the last route ' /projects/1 ' ,does ' /projects/1/boards ' sounds
>   better?

Any suggestions for the future `comps` ? Does ' /projects/1/boards/1/comps ' sounds a little more redundant?

And till now, my main concern about the `undefined` in URL remains unsolved. :(

---

UPDATE 2013-9-26

PROBLEM SOLVED!!!!!!

I will put the code later.

thanks to `@chooper and @Fred Jiles`

recommandation: [emberjs nested dynamic route segment returning null and unable to update child record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927948/emberjs-nested-dynamic-route-segment-returning-null-and-unable-to-update-child-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It needs to be `transitionToRoute('board', m)`.

Update: I also think your routes are not set up correctly. Try this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('projects',function(){
        this.resource('project',{ path: "/:project_id"});
    });
});
```

Which will result in `/projects/123` (where 123 is an id). Or:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('projects',function(){
        this.resource('boards',function(){
            this.resource('board',{ path: "/:board_id"});
        });
    });
});
```

Which will result in `/projects/boards/123` (where 123 is an id). Or:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('boards', {path: '/projects'}, function(){
        this.resource('board',{ path: "/:board_id"});
    });
});
```

Which will result in `/projects/123` (where 123 is an id). This will use `/projects` as URL but the `board` model.

I think the last version is what you are after, but it is not quite clear from your question.

Comment: thanks for the answer,but I don't have BoardRoute or a 'board' template。hope to hear more detail info from you

Comment: In my code I declare this:this.resource('boards',{ path: "/:project_id"}); could "the project_id"  cause the problem?

Comment: thank for your kind help, question solved finally. and  @Fred Jiles also give many valuable advice in this article.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15927948/emberjs-nested-dynamic-route-segment-returning-null-and-unable-to-update-child-r I'll refactor the code and put it up to fiddle later.